# sed replace every word with single quotes with double quotes

Tags: bash, sed, quotes

I'm trying to parse a file with single quotes, and want to change it to double quotes.

Sample data :

```
{'data':        ['my',
'my_other',
'my_other',
'my_other',
'This could 'happen' <- and this ones i want to keep',
],
'name': 'MyName'},
'data2': {'type': 'x86_64',
'name': 'This',
'type': 'That',
'others': 'bla bla 'bla' <- keep this ones too',
'version': '21237821972'}}}
```

Desired output :

```
{"data":        ["my",
"my_other",
"my_other",
"my_other",
"This could 'happen' <- and this ones i want to keep"
],
"name": "MyName"},
"data2": {"type": "x86_64",
"name": "This",
"type": "That",
"others": "bla bla 'bla' <- keep this ones too",
"version": "21237821972"}}}
```

I've already tried to do some regex with sed, but unlucky.
I understand why this is not working for me, just don't know how to go further to get data as i want.

```
sed -E -e "s/( |\{|\[)'(.*)'(\:|,|\]|\})/\1\"\2\"\3/g"
```

Cheers,

Comment: What's the final objective you're trying to solve? And is it ok to use python?

Comment: If this is a `JSON` file, recommend using `jq` tool (or) use the python json module

Comment: This are some python dicts and lists that i want to convert to json (with double quotes)

Comment: Is there any way you can distinguish between which quotes to keep and which ones to replace, because even if you go for a logic of keeping the mid sentence quote intact, i see a line where the quotes are changed in your desired Output.

Comment: No, there's nothing that i could tell that distinguish them. Sorry.

Comment: @Ricardo Ribeiro, Did you find the answer for your question? If so please share it for all.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert in jq so as per OP's question trying to answer in awk to substitute ' to " here.

```
awk -v s1="\"" '!/This could/ && !/others/{gsub(/\047/,s1) } /This could/ || /others/{gsub(/\047/,s1,$1)} 1'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
{"data":        ["my",
"my_other",
"my_other",
"my_other",
"This could 'happen' <- and this ones i want to keep',
],
"name": "MyName"},
"data2": {"type": "x86_64",
"name": "This",
"type": "That",
"others": 'bla bla 'bla' <- keep this ones too',
"version": "21237821972"}}}
```

Comment: That almost did it, but i want to keep the single quotes inside the string (the ones that says i want to keep).
Thanks in advanced,

Comment: "some text in 'single' quotes" like this :) perhaps i explain it baddly.
Sorry

Comment: @RicardoRibeiro, so whichever string is that in which you want to keep the quotes? any specific strings or any method to identify them? Please do let me know on same.

Comment: No, there's no way to identify them. Sorry. This is just some sample text.

Comment: @RicardoRibeiro, how come, there should be some specific text? some specific pattern, some specific place? Else how a program could be written if these things are not there? Also where you want me to fix my code?

Comment: You should fix the source of the problem to use proper quoting instead of trying to retrofit a fix after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

[image] We know that ‘sed’ command can search for a pattern and can replace that pattern with user provided new one

For example sed  “s/pattern1/pattern2/g”  filename.txt

Now the ‘sed’ command will search for pattern1 and if found it will replace with pattern2

For your requirement you just need to apply this rule. See below

First 
sed "s/^\'/\"/g”  yourfile

This will search for every newline with character    ‘    in the file and replace with    “

Next requirement is to search for pattern    ‘:    and replace with   “:

So add one more condition to it separated by   ;

sed "s/^\'/\"/g; s/\':/\":/g” yourfile

Just follow this algorithm till you reach you requirement

The final should be look like:-

sed "s/^\'/\"/g; s/\':/\":/g;s/{\'/{\"/g;s/\[\'/\[\"/g;s/\',/\",/g;s/\'}/\"}/g;s/: \'/: \"/g;" yourfile > newfil

(If the above command gives you error just use the command at the very beginning)

finally
mv   newfile   yourfile

Comment: "just use the command at the very beginning" -- don't make people type out the text from an image, use actual text.

Comment: this is the command sed "s/^\'/\"/g; s/\':/\":/g;s/{\'/{\"/g;s/\[\'/\[\"/g;s/\',/\",/g;s/\'}/\"}/g;s/: \'/: \"/g;" but while I paste it, it remove some of the character. I think it will not be difficult for anyone to see the image and type it in the command prompt.